# Is there anyway to make the following code more efficient and easier to read?

Tags: r, list, function

I have two lists, `rawmetadata` and `TPMMetadata` , each list contains multiple data frames. Now I'm making new vectors,`Response` and `RECIST`, based on the values of each data frame in each list. Consider this code:

```
Response = c(rawmetadata[[1]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[1]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[2]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[3]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[2]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[4]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[5]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[3]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[4]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[5]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[6]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[7]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[8]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[6]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[7]]$Benefit,
              TPMMetadata[[8]]$Benefit,
              rawmetadata[[9]]$Benefit)

RECIST <- c(rawmetadata[[1]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[1]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[2]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[3]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[2]]$recist, 
            rawmetadata[[4]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[5]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[3]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[4]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[5]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[6]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[7]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[8]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[6]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[7]]$recist,
            TPMMetadata[[8]]$recist,
            rawmetadata[[9]]$recist)
```

The order that you see here, is important. As you see the order of the lists used in making both vectors is exactly the same. I have also this vector, `samples`, that was made also with two different lists, `scoresraw` and `scorestpm`, like this:

```
samples <- c(colnames(scoresraw[[1]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[1]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[2]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[3]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[2]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[4]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[5]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[3]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[4]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[5]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[6]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[7]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[8]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[6]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[7]]),
             colnames(scorestpm[[8]]),
             colnames(scoresraw[[9]]))
```

The order for `samples` is also just like the order making `Response` and `RECIST`. The order of the "raw" lists and the "TPM" lists is exactly the same and they should stay that way.

Is there any way to make this process easier and shorter? I have more code blocks like this and it's taking a lot of space. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason the 1st element is taken from both list elements, whereas the other elements are not in the same order

Comment: This section of "Advanced R" by H. Wickham should be really helpful: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#fp-motivation (same holds for the whole book, in my opinion - and don't get discouraged by the title).

Comment: Based on the code showed, you may need a custom index.  Not clear without a reproducible example though.  Try `ind <- list(1, 1, 2:3, 2, 4:5, 3:5, 6:8, 6:8, 9)
             lst1 <- lapply(ind[c(TRUE, FALSE)], \(i) do.call(rbind, lapply(rawmetadata[i], \(x) x[c("Benefit", "recist")])))
             lst2 <- lapply(ind[c(FALSE, TRUE)], \(i) do.call(rbind, lapply(TPMMetadata[i], \(x) x[c("Benefit", "recist")])))
             out <- rbind(do.call(rbind, Map(rbind, lst1[-length(lst1)], lst2)), lst1[[length(lst1)]])` Now, `Response <- out$Benefit; RECIST <- out$recist`